# S3 PUT bucket access to all users though mobile application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I’m an upcoming aws developer and I am trying to understand the best practices. I have a mobile application and all the users will upload photos of their recipes through the app. I am trying to find a way to give limited access to my s3 bucket to my app for users to upload the images. Is there a way to do that with hard coding credentials on my app? So the bucket is private and all objects are private but my app needs to be put in the bucket. I don't know which to pick like AWS Cognito or S3 pre-signed URLs for the app to get limited access. Also, the solution should scale multi-region i.e on an Active-Active deployment it should be routed to the Closest Bucket t the user.

Thank you

Comment: Improve your Question! Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your question? This practice will considerably improve this problem.

Comment: what have you tried? any code? any documentation or example?